# HTML meta redirect equivalent javascript code to the old url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

I put this script into index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.history.pushState('other.html', 'Other Page', 'other.html');
    window.history.pushState('index.html', 'Initial Page', 'index.html');

    window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
        if (document.URL.indexOf("other.html") >= 0) {
            document.location.href = document.location;
        }
    });
</script>
```

And in other.html file I put this line in a meta tag in the head section.

http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://example.com/'

So when I run and click the browser back button for the first time it is going to other.html and redirect me to this link http://example.com/ and when I clicked the browser back button again it redirects me to the old index.html

This is working fine. What I need here to make the equivalent code of the HTML meta redirect. I don't want to put this tag into other.html and I want to create javascript code that doing the html meta tag right now.

Is that possible? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You already know how to do redirect using `location`. Did you try using that? What's wrong with meta tag approach if it's working?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in **head** tag of **other.html** file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href = "http://example.com";
</script>
```

It is equivalent to:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://example.com/'" />
```